# hapijs - how to pass headers while redirecting to another route

Tags: javascript, express, servlets, hapi.js

```
generateToken(request, reply) {
     let token = //JWT token generated 
     request.headers.Authorization = token;
     //also tried
     request.response.header('token' , token);
     reply.redirect('/newPath')
    }
```

The new path does not have these headers. I also tried to set the token from 'onPreResponse' stage but same result.
I am using hapi version 16.

Comment: you can set a cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added it as a search param to the redirect URL. The search params won't be sent to the server when requesting a URL, so the token shouldn't end up in any logs.

```
res.redirect(`http://appServer:5001/?key=value#jwt=${token}`)
const token = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams.get('jwt');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found quite an elegant solution using cookies:
I'm talking about the same jwt header you're talking about, but should generally work for any header and any page switch, even after visiting some other site.

Generate the token, presumably in a successful login, and save it to a cookie to be saved in the browser:

```
// generate a jwt token
let token = Jwt.token.generate('your_id', {
    key: jwtKey,
    algorithm: 'HS256'
}, {ttlSec: 24*60*60});
// save the token in a cookie
const response = h.response();
response.state("jwt_token", token, cookie_options);
```

Now, in a onPreAuth event, read the token from the cookie into a header:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    type: 'onPreAuth',
    method: (req, h) => {
      try {
        var pfx = your_jwt_strategy.httpAuthScheme;
        const server = req.server;
        const auth = server.auth;
        const config = auth.lookup(req.route);
        var t_data = req.state.jwt_token;
        if (!t_data && config.mode == 'required') {
          // if authentication is required and 
          // missing, will redirect to /login
          return h.redirect('/login').takeover();
        }
        // this header will be read by the
        // jwt authentication mechanism.
        req.headers.authorization = 
          pfx + ' '+t_data;
      }
      catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      return h.continue;
    }
  }
];
```

This tandem will auto save the new token in the browser cookie, thus ensuring its safe keeping and reloading upon each request, and loading it back in the request header upon a new browser request.